# how do i combinine/transparent seperated data

Tags: excel, vba

I have data for the year 2019 to 2021 and from 2016 to 2018. I want to combine the data and the KeyNumbers to follow, i was thinking it is best via VBA. But i am clueless on how to do it, so far i move the data from one sheet to this one, and here i have the data collected. But the years is seperated. I need it to be as shown from row R to T. This would be a big help for me, because i have 65 of these sheets. So a simple VBA would be so much help!

Thanks in advance

I tried to write VBA. It is getting there but mixing it up as result

```
    Sub x()

Dim lngDataColumns As Long
Dim lngDataRows As Long

lngDataColumns = 2
lngDataRows = 20


For t = 1 To lngDataRows

Range("n2").Offset(((t - 1) * lngDataColumns) - 1, 0).Resize(lngDataColumns, 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(Range("g24:h24").Offset(t).Value)

Range("o2").Offset(((t - 1) * lngDataColumns) - 1, 0).Resize(lngDataColumns, 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(Range("i24:j24").Offset(t).Value)
Next t

End Sub
    Sub y()



Dim lngDataColumns As Long
Dim lngDataRows As Long

lngDataColumns = 3
lngDataRows = 20



Range("p2").Offset(((t - 1) * lngDataColumns) - 1, 0).Resize(lngDataColumns, 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(Range("h5").Offset(t).Value)

    End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check [Pivot Tables](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html)

Comment: Thats it not VBA...

Comment: @AskeM. And your "question" is not asking a question. • Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question. • You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: In your question you said *i was thinking it is best via VBA*. Well, I just posted a different via, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastrowH As Long, Year As Long, i As Long, LastrowR As Long
    Dim Amount As Double
    Dim Key As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

         LastrowH = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

         For i = 2 To LastrowH
            'Check if Key start from DR (we assume that anything start with DR is key we need)
            If Left(.Range("H" & i).Value, 2) = "DR" Then 'Remove this line

                Key = .Range("H" & i).Value
                Amount = .Range("L" & i).Value
                Year = .Range("M" & i).Value
                LastrowR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
                    .Range("R" & LastrowR + 1).Value = Key
                    .Range("S" & LastrowR + 1).Value = Amount
                    .Range("T" & LastrowR + 1).Value = Year

                    If Year = 2018 Then

                        .Range("R" & LastrowR + 2 & ":R" & LastrowR + 4).Value = Key
                        .Range("S" & LastrowR + 2 & ":S" & LastrowR + 4).Value = Amount
                        .Range("T" & LastrowR + 2).Value = Year + 1
                        .Range("T" & LastrowR + 3).Value = Year + 2
                        .Range("T" & LastrowR + 4).Value = Year + 3

                    End If

            End If 'Remove this line

         Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

if you want to remove the DR ( if statement) remove the lines with **'Remove this line** at the end.

Comment: yea, i am getting compile error Expected end sub, and when i add End sub, i get error "for without next"

Comment: Make sure that you copy whole code. i test it again and it s works fine without any corrections. Scroll down until you find End Sub.

Comment: If i dont want to search for "DR" but just get the entire row of "h" what do i do then